# How to set parameters into URL HttpPost?

Tags: java, rest, http-headers

I'm using Apache HttpClient to send sms via my project, I have this  function:

```
  public void sendSMS(SMS sms) throws IOException {
    String auth = smsUsername + ":" + smsPassword;
    byte[] encodedAuth = encodeBase64(auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
    
    ObjectMapper oMapper = new ObjectMapper();    
    Map<String, Object> map = oMapper.convertValue(sms, Map.class);
    StringEntity params = new StringEntity(map.toString());       

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(smsEndpoint);
    post.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth));   
    post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    post.setEntity(params);       
    
    try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post)) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, () -> "the response: " + response.toString());
    }
}
```

My problem is the parameters into the url are empty, how do I resolve that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `smsEndpoint` contains your end-point URL and has not been modified in your code (code adds headers and entity). What parameters do you want to send as a part of the URL?

Comment: sms is a request body that not been send into the url

Comment: For POST, the values are sent in the request body and not in the URL. Are you trying to get the 'params' on the sever side?  You will get that in the request body.

Comment: This question explains the difference on how the data is sent in a POST request in great detail - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request

Answer (score 1):

Adding an entity to a `HttpPost` will add a body. If you want to add parameters, you have to add it to the url. At the moment your URL is the `smsEndpoint`.

You can just add the parameters there:

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param1", "value1"));

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(smsEndpoint);
URI uri = new URIBuilder(httpPost.getURI())
            .addParameters(nameValuePairs)
            .build();
httpPost.setURI(uri);
```

See also: https://www.baeldung.com/apache-httpclient-parameters!